# UITextFields NOT displaying, nor TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can not figure out why the text Fields are not displaying in the simulator. All the code looks fine, and the IBOutlets are connected. Every time I set the delegate = self to each IBOutlet name, in viewDidLoad, the app crashes. The same with the table View. I have tried creating functions, but xcode just does not seem to like "".delegate = self

```
import RealmSwift
import UIKit



class addCardViewController: UIViewController {
    
  
    
    private let realm = try! Realm()
    public var completionHandler: (()-> Void)?
    
   
    @IBOutlet weak var cardHolder: UITextField!
    

    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumber: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var expiryDate: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cvv: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Add New Card"
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "RED")
    
        
      
        

        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save Card", style: .plain, target: self,
        action: #selector(save))
      

  
}
    @objc private func cancel() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

    @objc private func save() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        
    }
}

extension addCardViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // return NO to disallow editing.
        print("TextField should begin editing method called")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // became first responder
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // return YES to allow editing to stop and to resign first responder status. NO to disallow the editing session to end
        print("TextField should snd editing method called")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // may be called if forced even if shouldEndEditing returns NO (e.g. view removed from window) or endEditing:YES called
        print("TextField did end editing method called")
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        // if implemented, called in place of textFieldDidEndEditing:
        print("TextField did end editing with reason method called")
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // return NO to not change text
        print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // called when clear button pressed. return NO to ignore (no notifications)
        print("TextField should clear method called")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
        print("TextField should return method called")
        // may be useful: textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AddCardItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var item: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
}


class WalletViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let button = UIButton()
    
    let table = UITableView()
    
    private var data = [AddCardItem]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "RED")
        button.setTitle("Add New Card", for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "yellow-2")
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "RED"), for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 800, width: 350, height: 50)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapAddButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    

    
    @objc private func didTapAddButton() {
        let rootVC = addCardViewController()
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(navVC, animated: true)
        
    }
}

    
    extension WalletViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
    }
    }

    
    extension WalletViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return data.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].item
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't see textfield in simulator?

Comment: Why not set delegate in storyboard ? If you have outlet it means you have storyboard or xib. If not you need to create the TextField programmatically.

Comment: imran exactly, nor the tableView. It crashes everytime I add the delegate in viewDidLoad. Nor can I add the delegate in storyboard, I have tried this and it does nothing Ptit